How to get Skype Name in local storage
I'm trying to get Skype Name(e.g. live:.cid.f4d4b42ec487f224) in my local storage.
I didn't find any method or tools to implement this. I am using windows operating system.
Please help to get this.
Thanks.
I trying to get these in local storage caches, but I didn't find.
